# Kinda homework but I just wanna learn

Tags: c

For context, I'm new to programming and we just had a quiz in class on making a program with the following instructions:
*Make a program that inputs your first name, last name, address, College Course, Year/section, and student ID. Then display these inputs + a new password via the combination of Year/section and studentID. Then, input that password to end the program.*
The quiz is already done but I still wanna learn how to do it. My problem is that when I input the password, it doesn't work. what could be the problem? How can This be done?
Further notes: Year/section and studentID inputs are expected to have single inputs with no spaces.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main (){
    char fname[25];
    char lname[10];
    char addr[50];
    char yr[10];
    char cr[50];
    char stid[15];
    char psswrd[50];

printf("Welcome to the Code! \n");
printf("Please Input your First Name: ");
fgets (fname, 25, stdin); 
printf("Please Input your Last Name: ");
fgets (lname, 10, stdin);
printf("Please Input your address: ");
fgets (addr, 50, stdin);
printf("Please Input your Course: ");
fgets (cr, 50, stdin);
printf("Please Input your College Year & Section: "); //cpe2a is an example of an answer.
scanf("%s",yr);
printf("Please Input your Student ID: ");
scanf("%s",stid);

printf("Your Details:\n");
printf("First Name: %s\n",fname );
printf("Last Name: %s\n",lname );
printf("Address: %s\n",addr );
printf("College Year: %s\n",yr );
printf("Course: %s\n",cr );
printf("Student ID: %s%s\n",stid );
printf("Your Password: %s%s", yr,stid );

printf("Please Input your New Password to Get Verified: ");
scanf("%s", psswrd);
printf("You Have Inputted: %s",psswrd);
    while (psswrd == "%s%s",yr, stid)
    {
        printf("Verefication Failed. \n");
        printf("Please Input Your Password: ");
        scanf("%s", psswrd);
        printf("You Have Inputted: %s",psswrd);
    }
    printf("Verification Successful! \nThank you for Using the Code!");

return 0;   
}
```

Comment: `while (psswrd == "%s%s",yr, stid)` That is incorrect for multiple reasons. It does nothing like what you  think it does. You need to use something like `sprintf` to construct a string and then use `strcmp` to do the compare.

Comment: "My problem is that when I input the password, it doesn't work." hmm... very unclear description. What doesn't work? Getting the input or comparing the input with year/section?

Comment: And since you are new to programming, here is an advice. Turn your compilers warning/error level to a high level (e.g. for gcc use the flags `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`). Fix **all** warnings/errors before you even try to run the program. Your code will generate warnings/errors exactly at the line where you have a bug. The compiler could have told you.

Comment: [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565)

Answer (score 5):

You have several errors, but the primary issue with your input is you have mixed `fgets()` (which you should use for every input) and `scanf()`. When you mix use of `fgets()` and `scanf()`, you must understand that `fgets()` will read and include the `'\n'` generated by the user pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the buffer it fills. `scanf()` with the `"%s"` conversion specifier does not.

However, there are two problems with `scanf()` here.

1. you fail to include a *field-width* modifier, making `scanf()` prone to exploit by buffer-overrun and using it that way is no safer than using `gets()`. See: [Why gets() is so dangerous it should never be used!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/3422102)
2. You mix `fgets()` and `scanf()` in attempt to avoid the `'\n'` at the end of `yr` and `stid` as well as in your read of `psswrd` where you should simply have read with `fgets()` and trimmed the `'\n'` from the end of the input using `strcspn()`.

Let's look at the example using only `fgets()` and see if it can be made to work properly.

First, instead of seven different string variables, let's clean that up by placing each of the strings in a `struct` so if you need to hold more than one student's data, you can simply use an array of struct, e.g.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLN   10    /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXID   15
#define MAXFN   25
#define MAXPW   50

typedef struct {          /* struct to hold student information */
  char  addr[MAXPW],      /* typedef for convenience */
        cr[MAXPW],
        psswrd[MAXPW],
        fname[MAXFN],
        stid[MAXID],
        lname[MAXLN],
        yr[MAXLN];
        
} student_t;
...
```

Now simply declare an instance of the struct (initialized to all zero) and a buffer to hold input of the verification password:

```c
...
int main (void) {
  
  char buf[MAXPW] = "";       /* buffer for input of password conf */
  student_t student = {0};    /* instance of struct initialized all zero */
  ...
```

Now simply read the data into your struct using `fgets()` and trim the `'\n'` read and included by `fgets()` using `strcspn()` as follows:

```c
  ...
  fputs ("Welcome to the Code!\n"
          "Please Input your First Name: ", stdout);
  if (!fgets (student.fname, MAXFN, stdin)) {
    return 0;
  }
  student.fname[strcspn (student.fname, "\n")] = 0;   /* trim \n from end */
  ...
```

Your remaining input happens the exact same way:

```c
  ...
  fputs ("Please Input your Last Name: ", stdout);
  if (!fgets (student.lname, MAXLN, stdin)) {
    return 0;
  }
  student.lname[strcspn (student.lname, "\n")] = 0;
  
  fputs ("Please Input your address: ", stdout);
  if (!fgets (student.addr, MAXPW, stdin)) {
    return 0;
  }
  student.addr[strcspn (student.addr, "\n")] = 0;
  
  fputs ("Please Input your Course: ", stdout);
  if (!fgets (student.cr, 50, stdin)) {
    return 0;
  }
  student.cr[strcspn (student.cr, "\n")] = 0;
  
  fputs ("Please Input your College Year & Section: ", stdout);
  if (!fgets (student.yr, MAXLN, stdin)) {
    return 0;
  }
  student.yr[strcspn (student.yr, "\n")] = 0;
  
  fputs ("Please Input your Student ID: ", stdout);
  if (!fgets (student.stid, MAXID, stdin)) {
    return 0;
  }
  student.stid[strcspn (student.stid, "\n")] = 0;
  ...
```

(**note:** there are no conversions requiring the use of `printf()`, simply use `fputs()` for output when you want end-of-line control, or `puts()` if you simply want a `'\n'` added)

Now create your combined password from `yr` and `stid`:

```c
  ...
  strcpy (student.psswrd, student.yr);    /* fill student password */
  strcat (student.psswrd, student.stid);
  ...
```

When you output data, you do not need one `printf()` (or `fputs()` or `puts()`) per-line, you simply need one call per continuous block of output, e.g.

```c
  ...
  printf ("\nYour Details:\n"
          "First Name: %s\n"
          "Last Name: %s\n"
          "Address: %s\n"
          "College Year: %s\n"
          "Course: %s\n"
          "Student ID: %s\n"
          "Your Password: %s\n", student.fname, student.lname,
          student.addr, student.yr, student.cr, student.stid,
          student.psswrd);
  ...
```

For your verification loop, simply loop continually until a valid verification password is provided, and `break` the verification-loop at that time, e.g.

```c
  ...
  while (1) {
    fputs ("\nInput your New Password to Get Verified: ", stdout);
    if (!fgets (buf, MAXPW, stdin)) {
      return 0;
    }
    buf[strcspn (buf, "\n")] = 0;
    
    if (strcmp (buf, student.psswrd) == 0) {  /* check password */
      break;
    }
    
    fputs ("  error: verification failed, passwords do not match.\n", 
          stderr);
  }
  ...
```

That's it aside for your closing:

```c
  ...
  puts ("Verification Successful! \nThank you for Using the Code!");
}
```

For convenience, the entire code (which you can copy/paste from above) is:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLN   10    /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXID   15
#define MAXFN   25
#define MAXPW   50

typedef struct {          /* struct to hold student information */
  char  addr[MAXPW],      /* typedef for convenience */
        cr[MAXPW],
        psswrd[MAXPW],
        fname[MAXFN],
        stid[MAXID],
        lname[MAXLN],
        yr[MAXLN];
        
} student_t;

int main (void) {
  
  char buf[MAXPW] = "";       /* buffer for input of password conf */
  student_t student = {0};    /* instance of struct initialized all zero */

  fputs ("Welcome to the Code!\n"
          "Please Input your First Name: ", stdout);
  if (!fgets (student.fname, MAXFN, stdin)) {
    return 0;
  }
  student.fname[strcspn (student.fname, "\n")] = 0;   /* trim \n from end */
  
  fputs ("Please Input your Last Name: ", stdout);
  if (!fgets (student.lname, MAXLN, stdin)) {
    return 0;
  }
  student.lname[strcspn (student.lname, "\n")] = 0;
  
  fputs ("Please Input your address: ", stdout);
  if (!fgets (student.addr, MAXPW, stdin)) {
    return 0;
  }
  student.addr[strcspn (student.addr, "\n")] = 0;
  
  fputs ("Please Input your Course: ", stdout);
  if (!fgets (student.cr, 50, stdin)) {
    return 0;
  }
  student.cr[strcspn (student.cr, "\n")] = 0;
  
  fputs ("Please Input your College Year & Section: ", stdout);
  if (!fgets (student.yr, MAXLN, stdin)) {
    return 0;
  }
  student.yr[strcspn (student.yr, "\n")] = 0;
  
  fputs ("Please Input your Student ID: ", stdout);
  if (!fgets (student.stid, MAXID, stdin)) {
    return 0;
  }
  student.stid[strcspn (student.stid, "\n")] = 0;
  
  strcpy (student.psswrd, student.yr);    /* fill student password */
  strcat (student.psswrd, student.stid);
  
  printf ("\nYour Details:\n"
          "First Name: %s\n"
          "Last Name: %s\n"
          "Address: %s\n"
          "College Year: %s\n"
          "Course: %s\n"
          "Student ID: %s\n"
          "Your Password: %s\n", student.fname, student.lname,
          student.addr, student.yr, student.cr, student.stid,
          student.psswrd);
  
  while (1) {
    fputs ("\nInput your New Password to Get Verified: ", stdout);
    if (!fgets (buf, MAXPW, stdin)) {
      return 0;
    }
    buf[strcspn (buf, "\n")] = 0;
    
    if (strcmp (buf, student.psswrd) == 0) {  /* check password */
      break;
    }
    
    fputs ("  error: verification failed, passwords do not match.\n", 
          stderr);
  }
  
  puts ("Verification Successful! \nThank you for Using the Code!");
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/student_verification
Welcome to the Code!
Please Input your First Name: Walt
Please Input your Last Name: Disney
Please Input your address: 111 Tune Ln.
Please Input your Course: Comedy
Please Input your College Year & Section: 22bs
Please Input your Student ID: 3123

Your Details:
First Name: Walt
Last Name: Disney
Address: 111 Tune Ln.
College Year: 22bs
Course: Comedy
Student ID: 3123
Your Password: 22bs3123

Input your New Password to Get Verified: 22bs3123
Verification Successful!
Thank you for Using the Code!
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.